# Create ssl certificate for java website running on Tomcat server

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, tomcat8, cloudflare

I have recently signed up on Cloudflare.com for ssl connection. But I don’t have any idea how to install ssl certificate on my java website running on Tomcat server. 
So can anyone please show me step by step how to activate ssl on my java website.

Comment: **With Cloudflare** your origin server isn't required to serve SSL at all, and if it does (which is a good idea) can use a selfsigned cert that would not be valid for real clients like browsers. See https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean- .

Comment: But cloudflare provides a universal ssl certificate. Can’t I use that ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'universal'. Cloudflare deploys numerous certs to its many servers for the (more numerous) domains they proxy, including yours; if they gave you the privatekey for such a cert you could impersonate at least hundreds or thousands of other people's websites, so they won't do that. Cloudflare does run their own 'origin ca' which will issue you a cert for your domain and key to use on your (origin) server, which they will then trust for 'strict'; see the bottom of the page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use keytool to create a keystore

   keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore your_site_name.jks

this will prompt you to create a password, do not forget it.

2. Install the certificate

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server -file cert.p7b -keystore your_site_name.jks

If asked to trust the certificate, choose yes (y).

3. Configure your SSL connector

open server.xml in a text editor. This file is commonly located in the conf folder of the Tomcat server's home directory.

Locate the connector with port 443 and uncomment it.

Specify the keystore file name and password.

It should look something like this:

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server" keystoreFile="/home/user_name/your_site_name.jks" keystorePass="your_keystore_password" />
```

Now save your changes and restart tomcat!

Comment: This would be a fairly good answer for a direct server if you filled in between 1 and 2: generate CSR, submit CSR to CA, submit other things like proofs and payment to CA, and get cert chain from CA, which is in p7b format only for some CAs. But for Cloudflare you don't need a real-CA cert in the first place.

Comment: How to generate csr. Becuase cloudflare is giving me two options: 1) use your own csr. 2) Generate csr on our website. Which one will work ?

Comment: generate csr on our website would be the easiest @ShadabKazi